# Google Places API returning no results

Tags: ios, json, google-places-api

I am following this tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit, but for some reason my app is returning:

Google Data: (
)

Here is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

#define kGOOGLE_API_KEY @"API PLACED HERE, LEFT BLANK FOR STACKOVERFLOW"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate,     CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCentre;
int currenDist;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@end
```

and my implementation file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//Make this controller the delegate for the map view.
self.mapView.delegate = self;

// Ensure that you can view your own location in the map view.
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

//Instantiate a location object.
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

//Make this controller the delegate for the location manager.
[locationManager setDelegate:self];

//Set some parameters for the location object.
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)toolBarButtonPress:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
UIBarButtonItem *button = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
NSString *buttonTitle = [button.title lowercaseString];
[self queryGooglePlaces:buttonTitle];

}

-(void) queryGooglePlaces: (NSString *) googleType {
NSString *url = [NSString     stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?  location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", currentCentre.latitude, currentCentre.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currenDist], googleType,     kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", url);

//Formulate the string as a URL object.
NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];

// Retrieve the results of the URL.
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data  waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                      
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

//The results from Google will be an array obtained from the NSDictionary object with the  key "results".
NSArray* places = [json objectForKey:@"results"];

//Write out the data to the console.
NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", places);
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
//Get the east and west points on the map so you can calculate the distance (zoom level)  of the current map view.
MKMapRect mRect = self.mapView.visibleMapRect;
MKMapPoint eastMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMinX(mRect),  MKMapRectGetMidY(mRect));
MKMapPoint westMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMaxX(mRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mRect));

//Set your current distance instance variable.
currenDist = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(eastMapPoint, westMapPoint);

//Set your current center point on the map instance variable.
currentCentre = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate methods.
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region =  MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(locationManager.location.coordinate,1000,1000);


[mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

@end
```

My console log of the final formatted URL is :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json? location=HIDDENLAT,HIDDENLONG&radius=995&types=bar&sensor=true&key=HIDDENAPI
```

I have replaced the generated lat, long and API values above but they were returned as the correct values?

Another SO answer I found said to add the:

```
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

which I did but this has not worked for me?

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2):

This could be a number of issues including your API key, your search radius, or your search "type", or a JSON parsing problem. However, the code should go exactly as Gary Stewart has it posted above. He even helped me find my answer just by asking the question...

Add `NSLog(@"%@", url);` after the URL string in the queryGooglePlaces methord as he does above. This logs the URL request to your console so you can ensure it's being compiled as expected. If it is but you're STILL not getting data back, then copy the URL you generated from your console and open it in a web browser. At the bottom of the generated page, it will tell you why you're not getting data.

From Google's Developer Documentation:

> The "status" field within the search response object contains the
> status of the request, and may contain debugging information to help
> you track down why the request failed. The "status" field may contain
> the following values:
>
> **OK** indicates that no errors occurred; the place was successfully
> detected and at least one result was returned. **ZERO_RESULTS** indicates
> that the search was successful but returned no results. This may occur
> if the search was passed a latlng in a remote location.
> **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT** indicates that you are over your quota.
> **REQUEST_DENIED** indicates that your request was denied, generally
> because of lack of a sensor parameter. **INVALID_REQUEST** generally
> indicates that a required query parameter (location or radius) is
> missing.

My problem was that I was sending a search "type" of "breakfast" rather than simply "food". Silly me, "breakfast" would be a keyword, not a type.

(Here's a list of supported types by the way: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?  location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@"
```

to

```
@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@"
```

(ie, no space after the ? in the url template string)

Comment: Sorry not sure why I put the space in that link but there isn't one on the generated URL?? [link]https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=LAT,LONG&radius=995&types=park&sensor=true&key=KEY[/link]@Brett

Comment: Ok the latest update is that if I use the 'browser API key' from my API console it works perfectly so any ideas what could be wrong with my IOS one!? I've even generated a new one to try and still nothing :(

Comment: @GaryStewart Did you ever solve this problem? My URL is being generated perfectly, but I'm still getting the mind-numbing "Google Data: ()" response. Tried all kinds of different API keys!